# Equivalent metrics define the same topology proof.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a set and $d_{1},d_{2}$ be two metrics on $X$. Define a metric to be equivalent if convergence of a sequence in one metric implies the convergence in the other.

I am having difficulty understanding a particular line of one version of the proof. The overall strategy is to show that if $U \subset X$ is open with respect to $d_{1}$, that through a contradiction, show that there must be a $d_{2}$ ball contained by $U$.

The proof begins by defining $u\in U$ and supposing $U$ is open in $d_{1}$. Suppose there is no ball of radius $r$ in the $d_{2}$ metric that is contained in $U$. Therefore, for every natural number $n$ there is a $x_{n}\in X\setminus U$ such that $d_{2}(x_{n},u) < 1/n$ and hence $x_{n}$ converges to $u$ in $d_{2}$.

I get that $d_{2}(x_{n},u) < 1/n$ implies convergence in $d_{2}$. I don't understand why there is necessarily a sequence in $x_{n}\in X\setminus U$ that has this property or why it is worded in this particular manner. If this is a standard Euclidean $n$-ball over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and I naively draw a diagram I can accept this, but for an arbitrary set and two arbitrary metrics, I am having trouble convincing myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't understand why we can find $x_{n}$ for each $n$, suppose by contradiction that there is some $m$ such that we *can't* find an element $x_{m} \in X - U$ with $d_{2}(x_{m}, u) < \frac{1}{m}$.

That means for all $x \in X$ with $d_{2}(x, u) < \frac{1}{m}$, $x \in U$ (since we just said we can't find an $x$ with distance less than $\frac{1}{m}$ away from $u$ that is in $X - U$ -- which means all elements $\frac{1}{m}$ distance from $u$ must be in $U$).  But that means the ball around $u$ of radius $\frac{1}{m}$ in the $d_{2}$ metric is in $U$, which contradicts our assumption that we can't find an open ball with the $d_{2}$ metric contained in $U$.

Comment: The OP seems to also be asking what we do then with the $x_n$. Since they converge to $u$ is $d_2$, they also must converge to $u$ in $d_1$, hence for all large enough $n$ we have $x_n\in U$, a contradiction which completes the proof.

Comment: That makes sense thank you! I think I was having so much trouble because I was viewing $x_{m}$ as a whole sequence instead of just treating it as a single element first.